# Can I pass an integer list from c# to prolog predicate?

Tags: c#, prolog, ffi, swi-prolog

I've written a predicate in prolog that verifies if the given matrix is a magic square or not. It works but I want to make a graphical interface using C#. I've searched on how to connect prolog to C# but haven't found anything on how to pass variables,or in my case integer lists from and to prolog.
I guess my questions are : is it possible? and if so how can I do it?

here's my predicate where 'Matrix'and 'X' are a List of lists .

```
diab(Matrix,X):-
    square_matrix(Matrix),
    lignediff(Matrix),
    lignesom(Matrix,Sum),
    transpose(Matrix,T),
    lignesom(T,Sum),
    diagonal1(Matrix,D1),
    somme(D1,Sum),
    diagonal2(Matrix,D2),
    somme(D2,X).
```

Comment: SWI-Prolog has a C API: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=calling-prolog-from-c . You will need to figure out how to call a C API from C# and how to link against the SWI-Prolog library.

Answer (score 0):

[SWIPLCS](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/contrib-swiplcs) is a package that would solve your problem. The documentation can be found [here](https://documentation.help/SbsSW.SwiPlCs/introduction.htm)